# Find Most Common Occurring Text Based on Lookup Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out a way to find the most common occurring value (text) in my spreadsheet based on a lookup value. For example, if my table is as follows:

[image]

1. I want to calculate the most common value chosen by user 234 (A in this case), user 524 (B in this case)... and so on.
2. I want to calculate the percent of the chosen value. So in the previous point, A was chosen ~67% of the time by user 234... and so on.

I'm not sure which formula to use. I am able to find the most common occurring value in column B using the formula below, but how can I do that for a specific value, a user ID in this case?

`=INDEX(B2:B16,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(B2:B16,B2:B16)),COUNTIF(B2:B16,B2:B16),0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems other suggested answer may not suit, so instead with a PivotTable (and CF) perhaps:

[image: SO20384049 example(2)]

Comment: I think this is the better way, and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Getting a bit carried away, I have created a table of all results, with:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$D2,$B:$B,E$1)
```

(use SUMPRODUCT if you do not have COUNTIFS), highlighted the maximum values for Choice by row (Conditional Formatting with `=E2=MAX($E2:$H2)`), then copied the formatting and labels within which to show the calculations for each of the proportions:

[image: SO20384049 example]